# Could not find an overload for “init” that accepts the supplied arguments - Stanford course work

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn swift now and following the standard online and first lecture's work is to build a calculator. I followed exactly the same code but it failed to compile. code as follow:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false

    @IBAction func touchDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
        let TextCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
        display.text = TextCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
        }
        UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
    }

    @IBAction func performOperation(sender: UIButton) {
        UserIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
        if let mathmaticalSymbol = sender.currentTitle{
            if mathmaticalSymbol == "π" {
                display.text = String(M_PI)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error message showed up on the line of display.text = String(M_PI).
it said "Could not find an overload for “init” that accepts the supplied arguments".
should be an easy question but I am new to Swift and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: // try like this display.text = "\\(M_PI)"

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: x code 6.2. too old?